# Download sheet as csv from googlesheet in python

Tags: python, google-sheets

When I download a sheet from google sheets it adds empty column so that each row matches the number of highest number of columns in that sheet. but when i try to download csv using following code
https://gist.github.com/xflr6/57508d28adec1cd3cd047032e8d81266
it does not add empty columns. how can i add these empty column using python

Comment: Are the manual downloads from google sheets CSV files as well?

Comment: Yes. These sheets are from Google sheets